# MYSQL Update Column with higher values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I'm having two tables in an mysql database. 
TABLE_A

```
|    id   |  val  |
|----------------|
|    a    |   1   |
|    b    |   5   |
|    c    |   5   |
|    d    |   4   |
|    e    |   5   |
|    f    |   7   |
|----------------|


 TEMPORARY TABLE_B
|----------------|
|    id   |  val  |
|----------------|
|    a    |   4   |
|    b    |   4   |
|    c    |   8   |
|    d    |   8   |
|    e    |   5   |
|    f    |   2   |
|----------------|

 TABLE_A after update
|----------------|
|    id   |  val  |
|----------------|
|    a    |   4   |
|    b    |   5   |
|    c    |   8   |
|    d    |   8   |
|    e    |   5   |
|    f    |   7   |
|----------------|
```

I want to update Table_A with values from Table_B, but only if they are higher. 
Has anyone a snippet for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses the update/join syntax:

```
update table_a a
inner join (select id, max(val) val from table_b group by id) b
    on b.id = a.id and b.val > a.val
set a.val = b.val
```

If there are no duplicate `id`s in `table_b`, no need for aggregation:

```
update table_a a
inner join table_b b
    on b.id = a.id and b.val > a.val
set a.val = b.val
```